# subdivision Surface Modifier not working alright

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I'm following a tutorial, and the teacher uses the subdivision Surface Modifier after finishing the modeling. and here is the result:
[image]

[image]

And when I do this, it's like jaggy on the edges:
[image]
How should I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Right-click and choose 'Shade Smooth' from the popup menu.

Comment: It seems that your model has some mistake,pls upload your file.